# Overloaded name "Jordan algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, notation

Yuriy Drozd in his book F*inite Dimensional Algebras* defines the set 
of all $n\times n$  matrices of the form

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
   \alpha_{1} & \alpha_{2} & \cdots & \alpha_{n-1} & \alpha_{n} \\
   0 & \alpha_{1} & \cdots & \alpha_{n-2} & \alpha_{n-1} \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & \alpha_{n-3} & \alpha_{n-2} \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  & \vdots\\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & \alpha_{1} & \alpha_{2} \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \alpha_{1} \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

with entries in some field $K$ to be the the Jordan algebra $J_n(K)$.

Looking up Jordan Algebras on for example Wikipedia the name seems to reefer to something completely different, for starters it's nonassociative.

My question is if my associative "Jordan Algebra" $J_n(K)$ might be known under some other standard name?

Comment: The one in wikipedia (the "abstract" jordan algebra) is the one I'm used to thinking of as standard. Isn't this matrix ring just isomorphic to $K[x]/(x^n)$?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuriy Drozd says that this is the Jordan algebra $J_n(K)$, a subalgebra of $M_n(K)$. Of course, there are other Jordan algebras, but he refers to it by $J_n(K)$, and it is just listed as an Example in the text (Example 3.).
By the way, we may also start from any associative algebra $A$, where we obtain another Jordan algebra $A^+$ by setting
$$
a\circ b:=\frac{ab+ba}{2}.
$$
In particular, we could take $A=M_n(K)$. Again, $A^+$ is called Jordan algebra $A^+$.